# Select a text range in CKEditor from javascript

Tags: ckeditor

I want to select a specific text in CKEditor. I used the following:

```
var sel = editor.getSelection();

var element = sel.root;
console.log(element);
sel.selectElement(element);
var findString = 'foobar';
var ranges = editor.getSelection().getRanges();
var startIndex = element.getHtml().indexOf(findString);

if (startIndex != -1) {
    ranges[0].setStart(element.getFirst(), startIndex);
    console.log(element.getFirst() +" - "+ startIndex);
    console.log(element.getFirst() +" - "+ startIndex + findString.length);
    ranges[0].setEnd(element.getFirst(), startIndex + findString.length);
    sel.selectRanges([ranges[0]]);
}
```

It works fine if it's a plain text without a line break.
If the text I want to select is after the second line or it's formatted, I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: IndexSizeError: DOM Exception 1

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 6):

I revisited your code and changed it "a little bit". The following code will select **all occurrences** of the word *"the"* in editor contents:

```
// Note: your instance name may differ.
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1, 
    selection = editor.getSelection(),
    root = selection.root,
    textNodes = [],
    ranges = [],
    range, text, index;

function getTextNodes( element ) {
    var children = element.getChildren(),
        child;

    for ( var i = children.count(); i--; ) {
        child = children.getItem( i );
        if ( child.type == CKEDITOR.NODE_ELEMENT ) 
            getTextNodes( child );
        else if ( child.type == CKEDITOR.NODE_TEXT )
            textNodes.push( child );
    }
}

// Recursively search for text nodes starting from root.
// You may want to search a specific branch starting from other element.
getTextNodes( root ); 

// Iterate over found text nodes. If some contains
// phrase "the", create a range that selects this word.
for ( i = textNodes.length; i--; ) {
   text = textNodes[ i ];
   index = text.getText().indexOf( 'the' );
   if ( index > -1 ) {
      range = editor.createRange();
      range.setStart( text, index );
      // Note: 3 is fixed length of "the". You may want to change it.
      range.setEnd( text, index + 3 ); 
      ranges.push( range );
   }  
}

// Select all ranges "containing" phrase "the".
selection.selectRanges( ranges );
```

Please note that if you run this code in Chrome or IE, only the first occurrence will be selected. **Only Firefox supports multiple selections** and the result should look like this:

[image: Multiple selections in Firefox]

I hope this example will help you fixing the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, But it does't fixed my problem. I am working on auto fill,i was able to get text before cursor.I want to select the text so that i can replace it with new text.**So, How can i Select the Text before cursor**

Comment: oleq: How can I apply style to selected items? I am using your code and when I try to apply style, e.g. `editor.execCommand('bold');` to selected elements after `selection.selectRanges( ranges );` line I get an exception: **Uncaught IndexSizeError: Index or size was negative, or greater than the allowed value.**